# Strange EclipseLink error - won't allow a table named 'User', other names work fine

Tags: jakarta-ee, eclipselink, derby, open-liberty

I'm writing an application in Open Liberty. I've got this persistent entity (shortened for simplicity):

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
}
```

This causes the following error:

```
[INFO] [WARNING ] CWWJP9991W: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.3.v202208190922): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
[INFO] Internal exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "User" at line 1, column 14.
[INFO] Error number: 30000
[INFO] Call: CREATE TABLE User (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
[INFO] Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE User (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))")
```

Replacing "User" in the table name with anything else fixes this and makes the app work as expected.

Here's my persistence.xml file. Not sure if it's needed here. I'm using a Derby database. Following the answer in this thread did not solve this: [SQLSyntaxErrorException on creating tables in Apache Derby using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248076/sqlsyntaxerrorexception-on-creating-tables-in-apache-derby-using-jpa)

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="jpa-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/my-project</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                      value="create"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action"
                      value="create"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target"
                      value="createDDL.ddl"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`USER` is a reserved word in Apache Derby. Refer to the list of [reserved words](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.16/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html).  A solution is to use the `Table` annotation to specify a non-conflicting name value for the table, such as,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {
```